# How to fix "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found" if connecting .NET Core with Solr using Solr.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, solr, .net-core, solrnet

I wanted to establish a connection from my running .NET Core application with a local running solr instance using Solr.NET. The problem is that i always get an 404 Error when trying to query solr.

Here is the code:

In the Startup.cs i added the Instance to IServiceCollection with:

```
services.AddSolrNet("https://localhost:8982/solr");
```

In my controller i tried this:

```
        List<AppointmentSearchResult> content = new List<AppointmentSearchResult>();
        SolrQueryResults<AppointmentSearchResult> results = _solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("locked", "true"));
        foreach (AppointmentSearchResult result in results)
        {
            content.Add(result);
        }

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);

        return this.Content(json);
```

The AppointmentSearchResult class looks like this:

```
public class AppointmentSearchResult
    {
        [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [SolrField("locked")]
        public bool? locked { get; set; }

        [SolrField("unique_key")]
        public string unique_key { get; set; }

        [SolrField("busy")]
        public bool? busy { get; set; }

        [SolrField("done")]
        public bool? done { get; set; }

        [SolrField("duration")]
        public string duration { get; set; }

        [SolrField("customerid")]
        public double customerid { get; set; }

        [SolrField("planning")]
        public string planning { get; set; }

        [SolrField("employee_id")]
        public int? employee_id { get; set; }

        [SolrField("date")]
        public DateTime date { get; set; }

        [SolrField("done_date")]
        public DateTime? done_date { get; set; }

        [SolrField("calendar_event_id")]
        public string calendar_event_id { get; set; }

        [SolrField("note")]
        public string note { get; set; }
    }
```

Is this the right way to do this? I always get the error: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

It would be great if someone has suggestions for me!

Best regards, Andreas

Comment: Are you using an actual https connection to your localhost? Is that your Solr host or a different httpd? Does the URL work in your browser? Does Solr's server log show any requests happening? Does it work with curl or wget from the command line?

Comment: Yes, i installed a local ssl certificate and i can access Solr in the browser without any certificate issues. With a normal request from command line to https://localhost:8982/solr/Appointments/select/?q=*:*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on, i'm able to get data from solr but not with Solr.NET

Comment: According to the source the URL is supposed to include the core/collection name. `<param name="url">The url for the solr core.</param>`. Try `https://localhost:8982/solr/Appointments` instead. And watch the Solr log to see what request is actually being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for SolrNet v1.0.17 shows two IServiceCollection additions, one for the general solr instance, as you did, and another for the specific core with your document type specified. E.g.

```javascript
services.AddSolrNet("https://localhost:8982/solr");
services.AddSolrNet<AppointmentSearchResult>("https://localhost:8982/solr/core1");
```

https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Initialization.md

This is how I have done it in my Startup.cs, and have no problems like the one you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Is solr connection requires username and password? Try this.

```
services.AddSolrNet(o =>
            {
                o.ServerUrl = "https://localhost:8982/solr";
                o.UserName = "sa";
                o.Password = "sa";
            });
```

Comment: I can access Solr in the browser without any credentials with "https://localhost:8982/solr"